# How does one use windows authentication with a saturn or giraffe app?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, f#-giraffe, saturn-framework

I am very new to Saturn and Giraffe. I am trying to configure a saturn web app to use windows authentication for an intranet app - ultimately I want to run it with IIS. In the old world of asp.net it is trivial but in the saturn(giraffe(asp.net core)) world doesn't seem so, at least not for the moment. Windows authentication doesn't seem very popular with saturn or giraffe. See this google request: https://www.google.com/search?q=f%23+saturn+giraffe+%22windows+authentication%22.

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@vaibhavrb999/windows-authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-angular-web-application-5570981134d1) which is very close to what I want to achieve using an asp.net core web app. I need to make the jump to giraffe or saturn (I started with saturn - if I can't figure it out I am going down one level). This article was useful as well: [Adding a button for google signin using f#/fable/asp.net/react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275762/adding-a-button-for-google-signin-using-f-fable-asp-net-react/).

Any suggestions?

An interesting thing I noticed in VS 2019, when I try to create an F# based Asp.net Core web application I cannot change the authentication on the last page of the wizard. The Change button under Authentication is disabled. However, if I select C# as the base language I can do it.

Thanks

Comment: If you have an `HttpContext` (e.g. in a Saturn handler) and IIS is configured, you should be able to at least identify the user with `ctx.User.Identity.Name`. Does that part work?